# How to fix a stuck stellar node after picking up an incorrect block?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, nodes

I run two different watcher stellar nodes and they have both gotten stuck after picking up an invalid / incorrect block (i.e. the block hash of my node's top block does not match the block of the same height on block explorers).

Is there some way to delete the top block from Stellar's database or reignest it somehow or do I just need to re-sync my nodes from scratch?

Our invalid block is height 31782710.
I have tried using `horizon db reingest range 31782709 31782710` with no luck.

---

Edit: I am just resyncing my node for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to re-build your node to recover. In order to avoid this issue, please make sure to upgrade your nodes to the latest stellar-core version (as it sounds like you ran into an issue which got fixed in a later version)